# Angular-Foundation modal resolve

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, angular-foundation

I developing  common alert modals  for error , warning , confirm with angular-foundation modal.  My problem is that , I can not pass variable to modals . 
The modal Content:

```
 <h3 class="caps">{{ alertmessage }}</h3>
   <p>{{ alertdetail }}</p>
```

The open alert service:

```
appCommonServiceModule.factory('AlertModalService' , function($modal ,$rootScope){
       function AlertModalService(){
           this.openAlertModal = function($scope,type ,message , detail , successCallback ,cancelCallback ){
               var  templateUrl = ASSETS_PATH+'app/pages/templates/alert/';
               var  className = "reveal-modal small alert-modal ";
               if(type == "SUCCESS"){
                   templateUrl = templateUrl+"success.html";
                   className += "success-modal"
               }
                   $scope.message = message;
                   $scope.detail = detail;
                     var modalInstance  = $modal.open({
                         templateUrl : templateUrl,
                         controller : 'AlertBaseController',
                         backdrop: 'static',
                         windowClass:className,
                         scope:$scope,
                         resolve : {
                             alertmessage: function(){
                                 return $scope.message;
                             },
                             alertdetail :function(){ return $scope.detail; 
                     }
                         }
                     });
                     modalInstance.result.then(function(){
                          if(successCallback){
                              successCallback();
                          }
                     },function(){
                          if(cancelCallback){
                              cancelCallback();
                          }
                     });
           }
       }
       return  new AlertModalService();
    });
```

I can't  find a solution.
Thanks  for your helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your factory needs to have defined something like interface to be able sharing its data with controller:

```
appCommonServiceModule.factory('AlertModalService' , function($modal, $rootScope) { 
   // [...] your code

   service = {
      getModalData: getModalData
   };
   return service;

   function getModalData() {
      var modalData = {};
      modalData.message = message;
      modalData.detail = detail;
      return modalData;
   }

   // [...] your code
});
```

Secondly, you need the controller to display data in your HTML. You have already defined one (`controller: 'AlertBaseController'` in your code) so you can use it:

```
appCommonServiceModule.controller('AlertBaseController',  function(AlertModalService, $scope) {
   var modalData = AlertModalService.getModalData();
   $scope.alertmessage = modalData.message;
   $scope.alertdetail = modalData.detail;
});
```

Now you are able to use it in your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="appCommonServiceModule">
   <div ng-controller="AlertBaseController">
      <h3 class="caps">{{alertmessage}}</h3>
      <p>{{alertdetail}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I haven't tested it because I don't have the whole code but something like this should work.